# Variables set in middleware are null in constructor of a resource controller but have value(not null) in other methods of the controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I am using a middleware for my resource controller and in that middleware I set some global variables. Now I want to access those variables in the constructor of my controller but I get null value when I try to access those variables in the constructor while I receive not null value if I access them in any other method of that controller. I am using Laravel 5.6. Following is its code.

Controller:

```
class PhaseController extends ApiController
{
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->middleware('myMiddleware');
       $myVar = $request->myVar;
    }
 }
```

Middleware:

```
class myMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    $explodedPath = explode("/",$request->path());
    $request["myVar1"] = $explodedPath[5];
    //Code here
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

This is happening because request object is received before calling middleware so even I am modifying request object in middleware, Constructor is still using the old state of request object. Here I need to refresh the request object to get its new state. But I don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the request ParameterBag:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $parts = explode('/', $request->path()); 
    $request->attributes->add(['myVar1' => data_get($parts, 5)]);

    // Code here

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$myVar = $request->get('myVar1');
```

Edit:

---

If you would require route params in your controller, why not use

```
$request->route()->parameters();
```

or

```
$request->route('parameter_name'); // where name is based on the name in your route definition.
```

?

Comment: My route will vary as I am using same controller for different types of requests. That is why I am exploding path@Robert.